# Unable to solve Ruby hash

Tags: ruby, watir

I want to select the radio button with respect to the argument passed while calling the function

Below is the HTML code in text.html page:

```
<td>
     <input name="names" value="a" type="radio">Text1
     <input name="names" value="b" type="radio">Text2
</td>
```

Below is the Ruby script:

```
require 'watir'

browser = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome)

browser.window.maximize

browser.goto('file:///C:/text.html')

def select_names(browser, name)
    select_name_hash = {
        'a' => 'First',
        'b' => 'Second'
    }

    if browser.radio(:name => 'names', :value => "#{select_name_hash[name]}").present?
        browser.radio(:name => 'names', :value => "#{select_name_hash[name]}").set
        message = "Select #{name} - SUCCESS"
    else
        message = "Select #{name} - FAILURE"
    end

    return message
end

p select_names(browser, 'First')
```

I am getting the output as:

```
"Select First - FAILURE"
```

Could anyone please help. I want the output to be success. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to fetch hash key by its value. You may do it as follows:

**Ruby 1.9** and greater:

```
select_name_hash.key(name)
```

**Ruby 1.8**:

```
select_name_hash.index(name)
```

Comment: I want the hash to be the same way as I mentioned and I dont want to use invert. Is there any way for looping and finding out the proper output?

Comment: @AshwinRaoT I've updated my answer. You may fetch hash key by its value

Answer (score 0):

If your variable `name` is equal to `First` then you should initialize `select_name_hash` like:

```
select_name_hash = {
    'First' => 'a',
    'Second' => 'b' 
}
```

**UPD**

For your `select_name_hash`

```
> select_name_hash.rassoc('First').first
=> "a"
```

or

```
> select_name_hash.key('First')
=> "a
```

Comment: I want the hash to be the same way as I mentioned and I dont want to use invert. Is there any way for looping and finding out the proper output?

Comment: @AshwinRaoT I think in UPD one of possible solutions